# plot minimum value grouped by different variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset of repeated measurements (hb) for patients (record_id) over several days. I have included an example below

> record_id Day hb
>   1   0   122
>   1   1   90
>   1   2   71
>   1   3   71
>   2   0   139
>   2   1   130
>   2   2   119
>   2   3   106
>   3   0   89
>   3   1   126
>   3   2   127
>   3   3   110
>   4   0   90
>   4   1   86
>   4   2   82
>   4   3   78
>   5   0   118
>   5   1   108
>   5   2   95
>   5   3   94

I wish to find out the minimum value for "hb" for each patient:
 #nadir Hb by patient

```
x1 <- aggregate(hb~record_id, data=df, FUN=function(df) c(min=min(df), count=length(df)))
summary(x1)
```

Would anyone be kind enough to show me how I could plot a histogram of these minimum values? Thank you very much for your time, Annemarie

Comment: you can use this library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(record_id) %>% summarise(min = min(hb))  please look at this question that we answered for max http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620240/find-max-values-of-a-column-in-a-time-series-dataset/36620406#36620406

Comment: Like this?: `hist(tapply(df$hb, df$record_id, min))`

Comment: Brilliant, that is embarrassingly simple! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Annemarie Please provide the whole dataset

Comment: @DatamineR I hadn't put in na.rm=TRUE. It's working well now, thanks

Comment: @Learner Thank you. When I use your code, I can only get the minimum hb for the whole dataset (ie 78), rather than for each record_id. Is there something fundamental I'm doing wrong? Thanks